# Control Batch files with php

Tags: php

I'm running a socket connection, for retrieving live data for subscriptions. The problem is that I can only have 1 subscription, per connection. I have done a bit of testing and running multiple socket connections, is no problem as long as they are different sessions. So, I think the logical reason and easier is to run multiple connections. Each connection is ran through a PHP script, using CLI. Now, a live operator can control the connections, which run off php, but giving an employee server access is kind of risky. Now my question is:

Can a PHP script from a browser, send a custom php.exe command and launch CLI?

Comment: You can use just `exec('php myscript.php arg1')`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

on a windows system its a bit tricky to start a batch file as a new process in background.

You need to build an .bat file (in php or by your own) like this:

C:/path/to/php/php.exe -f C:/your/php/file.php var1 var2

and your php code, to start this batch file in background:
(the 0 will hide this CMD window)

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->Run('cmd /C '.$patch_to_batch_file, 0, false);
```

regards
Thomas